# Test-Path -Leaf meaning

Tags: powershell

I'm learning PowerShell and have seen this used on Technet:

```
Test-Path -Path $DirectoryPath -PathType 'Leaf'
```

What is the meaning of the path type `Leaf`?

It is clear what the `Container` and `Any` path types are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `Test-Path` help:

```
-PathType <TestPathType>
    Specifies the type of the final element in the path. This cmdlet returns $True if the element is of the specified
    type and $False if it is not. The acceptable values for this parameter are:

    - Container. An element that contains other elements, such as a directory or registry key. - Leaf. An element that
    does not contain other elements, such as a file. - Any. Either a container or a leaf. Tells whether the final
    element in the path is of a particular type.
```

Specifically:

> -Leaf. An element that does not contain other elements, such as a file.

The easiest way to get this information from the console is `Get-Help Test-Path -Parameter PathType`

Answer (score 5):

##### Generally speaking:

- `Leaf` : file
- `Container` : folder / directory
- `Any` : file *or* folder

.

---

The metaphor is that your file system is like a tree hierarchy, with each branching *node* either being able to branch further (folder), or being a *leaf* node that cannot branch further (file).

Illustrated example:

[image: illustrated file system tree hierarchy showing container nodes and leaf nodes]

Answer (score 3):

If you see the PowerShell documentation for the same, it will be clear. Use the below command

`Get-Help Test-Path -Full`

If you look at the description of all the parameters which `Test-Path` supports, you will come across the `-PathType` parameter which says

```
 -PathType <TestPathType>
 Specifies the type of the final element in the path. This cmdlet returns $True if the element is of the
 specified type and $False if it is not. The acceptable values for this parameter are:

 - Container. An element that contains other elements, such as a directory or registry key. - Leaf. An element
 that does not contain other elements, such as a file. - Any. Either a container or a leaf. Tells whether the
 final element in the path is of a particular type.

 Required?                    false
 Position?                    named
 Default value                None
 Accept pipeline input?       False
 Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

So `-container` refers to directories, folders or sub-folders while `leaf` refers to files. If you need more help, you can look into the examples too using `Get-Help Test-Path -Examples`